# Silent install of apps (.ipa) to iPad

Tags: ios, command-line, installation, ipa, silent-installer

To speedup iOS development would be great to have a way to install ipa on device in automated way.

TestFlightApp does great job to help ipa distribution. I looking for addition steps that allows putting ipa on device without user actions. From command line :-). It doesn't matter via USB or WiFi.

Any inputs?

Stan

Comment: Knowing Apple this is most likely not possible.

Comment: and sounds like a bad idea because this would likely allow malware onto the device.

Comment: Agree, I don't wait for such feature from Apple. But maybe from iFunbox or others. Note that I have correctly signed app.

Comment: There are a variety of MDM (Mobile Device Management) products which you may consider looking into that can do this, if the target devices are iOS 5.x+ for silent installs, else on <iOS 5.x then a user (or someone) would have to accept the install.

Comment: @Luke Haven't found any docs on how to perform a silent install. mdm push does work (InstallApplication command). But there is still a popup asking to install the app. Is there a special thing/flag for silent installs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apple Configurator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) requires OS X 10.7.2, but it seems to have the functionality you are looking for.  It can do up to 30 devices at a time.